# Why max length function in HTML is not working?

Tags: html

I am doing a calculator and maxlenght is not working. After I set maxlength to 12, when clicking calculator buttons it do more then 12.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="12" name="display" id="result" disabled placeholder="0">
```

Comment: Please provide more information, such as the platform you are using. Also, can we assume that there are angle brackets around your tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the html from your comment. The `maxlength` property of an input tag only applies when the user is typing into it. When you set the result programmatically, it is not respected.

```js
document.getElementById("result").value = "1234567890123456";
```

```html
<div id="history" placeholder="0"></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="12" name="display" id="result" disabled placeholder="0">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" class="buttons1" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but the following works:

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="12" name="display" id="result"  placeholder="0">
```

Comment: it's not working when I run. Tried chrome and IE. This on site works just fine, but not on my page.

Comment: <table>
                    <div id = "history" placeholder="0"></div>
                <input type="text" maxlength="12" name="display" id="result" disabled
                        placeholder="0" />
                

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" class="buttons1" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'" />
                    </td>


                </tr>